# How to create a gradient fill on the inner edge of an object with Raphael?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I have a dynamically generated graph that illustrates the range of items that will fit within a container, relative to the item's width and thickness. I'm trying to show that the items near the edge of the "fit range" might not be as good of a fit as those closer to the middle of the graph. To do this I'd like to fill my shape with green, which has a gradient that turns to yellow around the edges. This yellow area should be of uniform thickness around the entire inside edge, as illustrated in the image below. How might I accomplish this with Raphael? I know how to do a solid fill; the gradient is where I'm having difficulty. Thanks in advance for your help!

[image: Gradient Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory it should be possible to do this by slicing the graph into four triangles.

[image: Slice the graph into four rectangles]

Each triangle can then be filled with a gradient that is mostly your solid color but at one end it turns into your edge color. By setting the right angle on the gradient you can make it look like only the edges on the graph have a different color.

[image: Graph with edges in another color]

I've created the rectangle above using the following code.

```
var slice1 = paper.path("M200 200L100 100L300 100").attr({
    "fill": "90-#0f0:70-#ff0:95",
});

var slice2 = paper.path("M200 200L300 100L300 300").attr({
    "fill": "0-#0f0:70-#ff0:95",
});

var slice3 = paper.path("M200 200L300 300L100 300").attr({
    "fill": "270-#0f0:70-#ff0:95",
});

var slice4 = paper.path("M200 200L100 300L100 100").attr({
    "fill": "180-#0f0:70-#ff0:95",
});
```

Your case will be a bit more complex though. You will have to first find the middle of the graph to be able to slice it into triangles. Then you need to find the angle for each of the gradients.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Jonas. I fiddled with this a good while, but since my graph varies in shape, it was very difficult to get the gradient to look smooth the whole way around. I ended up abandoning the gradient idea, though it would have been much prettier, and just drew two shapes with the green one on top of the yellow. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Evening,

It's not as easy as it looks like it should be. Probably due to an issue with how to implement it in VML.

The best I was able to do is to use a slightly larger clone of your target object behind the original, and then use a gradient fill on it.

I've made an example [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amadanNM/kcFUN/)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Obviously the complexity of your target object will decide whether this is an effective way to get the result you want. Your mileage may vary...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a radial gradient on an overllying ellipse but that will leave a rather large corner of yellow
To find the centre of your object use good old getBBox()